# How to share the article content using facebook share button from a custom module in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, facebook-sharer

Hi Iam very new to drupal

Iam creating a custom module for facebook like and share buttons(i.e Referring the facebook share and like module).I have successfully created the facebook like and its functionality.But I have a problem with facebook share button..

**when Iam sharing the content using the facebook share button,Its just sharing the link of my article instead of content of the article(i.e Title,description..etc)**

This is the code which I have used

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?<?php print $sharesrc;?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true" style="height:22px;"></iframe>
```

Here **$sharesrc** is

```
"href=articleurl&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;font=arial&amp;height=80&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;locale=en_US&amp;"
```

I have even checked with existing facebook share modules like

https://www.drupal.org/project/facebookshare

https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis

https://www.drupal.org/project/service_links

I have implemented ogp also

```
<meta property="og:type" content="Article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Another Test article">
<meta property="og:url" content="urlofmyarticle">
```

But none of them is sharing the article content using facebook share button.Please help with this.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the code from the Button Generator correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

You are missing the "href" parameter:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=<?php echo $sharesrc;?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;appId=xxx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Btw, it is recommended to ALWAYS use an App ID.

Edit: Ok, you are adding href to the variable already. But you should remove `send=false` and `action_type`. Those are flags for the Like Button, not the Share Button. And maybe it´s just not documented, but there is no `colorscheme` for the Share Button in the docs either.

Of course you need to make sure to have all the necessary Open Graph tags too: http://ogp.me/

...and if it STILL does not work, put the link in the debugger and refresh the OG data: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @luschn The $sharesrc is getting the href and layout of the button too.I have edited my question please check it

Comment: Thanks @luschn but I removed send,action type and also implemented the ogp but none of them is sharing my article content

Comment: then try to put the link in the debugger, i´ve added a link. if the refresh does not work, i´d need a test link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after implementing openGraph meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
```

And it turned out to be caching from facebook side. Just try to share another article you have not shared before.